# Data from address?

Tags: transactions, balance

How to get balances and transactions of a Bitcoin address? I'm looking into bitcoin development and relatively new to the space. - Tien

Comment: Using which wallet software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this data by hosting Blockbook and using REST query:

```
GET /api/v2/address/<address>[?page=<page>&pageSize=<size>&from=<block height>&to=<block height>&details=<basic|tokens|tokenBalances|txids|txs>&contract=<contract address>&secondary=usd]
```

Or you can simply use the [Blockbook RPC Add-on](https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/blockbook-rpc-add-on) of [QuickNode Marketplace](https://www.quicknode.com/marketplace).

Once you have the Add-on enabled on your QuickNode Bitcoin RPC. The method to be used is `bb_getaddress` and the code should look something like this:

```javascript
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "method": "bb_getaddress",
  "params": [
    "ADDRESS_TO_GET_TXs_AND_BALANCES",
    {
      "page": 1,
      "size": 1000,
      "fromHeight": 0,
      "details": "txids"
    }
  ]
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("QUICKNODE_BTC_RPC_URL_HERE", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```